# Calculating generalized derivatives for piecewise constant functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x< 0 \\
2 & \mbox{if } x=0 \\ 1 &\mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}$$ $$f_1(x) = \begin{cases} -2 &\mbox{if } x< 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0 \\ 1 &\mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}$$ $$f_2(x) = \begin{cases} -2 &\mbox{if } x< 0 \\
-2 & \mbox{if } x=0 \\ 0 &\mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}$$

Then $f(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. My notes say that the generalized derivative of $f$ is $df_1-df_2$. (I'm not sure what that means). How can we calculate $df_1-df_2$?

Comment: It seems to me that we could define further functions that have as differences $f_1,f_2$ and use the definition of generalized derivative to get the derivatives of $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: @abiessu I'm not sure either. My notes say that "**by definition**, the generalized derivative $f'$ of $f$ is $df_1-df_2$. Calculate $f'$." So I assume there's some way to determine this $df_1-df_2$, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @abiessu What's the definition of generalized derivative that you know?

Comment: I don't know any definition, I'm following the text of your question and observing that a further separation into "simple" functions similar to $f_2$ might be good.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the "weak derivative"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming here that generalized derivatives mean distributional derivatives. See this link for the definitions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29

Essentially the derivative of a locally integrable function $f$ (The example you gave is a locally integrable function) is by definition the linear functional

$\phi \mapsto -\int \phi'(x)f(x) dx$

where $\phi$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function with compact support. We can calculate the derivative of $f$ directly from this without decomposing into $f_1$ and $f_2$. As per the definition, the value of $f$ at a single point does not matter, so we can assume that $f(0) = 0$. This now becomes the standard Heaviside function and hence $f' = \delta$, where $\delta$ is the dirac delta "function".

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right with the definition. But how can we calculate $df_1$ and $df_2$, and subtract them?